# How to show a partial message from a result?

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox, button and an alertbox. Whenever someone types something into the textbox and clicks the button, it requests from a web page url and changes the alertbox text to a message of up to 43 letters/numbers (mixed). How do I change it so that it only shows the first 25 letters/numbers (mixed)?

It's currently showing something like this:

```
SUCCESS: 127.0.0.1 works - webpage.com
```

I want it to only show:

```
SUCCESS: 127.0.0.1 works
```

Either that or just to grab the numbers with dots and show them as a result. For example: `127.0.0.1`.  Note, the requests change every time, so the IP isn't the same.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub FlatButton2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatButton2.Click
        Dim Website2 As New WebClient
        Dim WebsiteIW As String = Website2.DownloadString("http://website.com/" + FlatTextBox1.Text)
        FlatAlertBox1.Text = WebsiteIW
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        FlatLabel2.Visible = True
        FlatAlertBox1.Visible = True
        FlatLabel3.Visible = True
```

Comment: Put the code in pastebin since it got messed up on here. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/B298RPXU

Comment: Tip, to paste code, use the code button in the toolbar ie `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MaxLength property of the textbox to limit the length of the input string. Otherwise, you can use the Substring string method to cut the string size before you communicate with the web page.

Comment: You can limit the textbox length in the Designer, or Text1.MaxLength = 45. To limit the size of a string, you can use something like "if s.length > 45 then s = s.substring(0, 45)"

Comment: textbox length has nothing to do with it, i want to somehow limit the length of the result which gets put in the alertbox?

Comment: Assign it to a string and use Substring to limit that before it's displayed.

Comment: Actually i fixed the spacing, but the result is on line 2 and i need it on line 1, how do i do that?